# ¿Cómo traer dato de la bd en java?

Tags: java

quisiera saber como traer un dato de la bd, llevo esto

```
  try {
        conexion objConexion = new conexion();
      
        ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM contador");
        
         Object[] oUsiario = {resultado.getString("formVendiTotal")};
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
    }
```

si voy bien?, ahora como meto ese dato en una variable,? o si voy mal como lo haría?
la bd es esta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

me quedo así el código, lo saque en la variable y le coloque un JOptionPane para ver si traje el dato

```
                try {
        conexion objConexion = new conexion();
        ResultSet resultado = objConexion.consultarRegistros("SELECT * FROM contador");
        Object[] oUsiario = {resultado.getString("formVendiTotal")};
      
        for (int i = 0; i < oUsiario.length; i++){
          oUsiario[i] = resultado.getString("formVendiTotal");
          
        } 
        String mT =oUsiario[1].toString();
        // para saber que es lo que traje
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, mT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, e);
        }
```

y me manda este error

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hay varias formas de recorrer un ResultSet, lo mas común es usar [`next()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next\(\)). También te puede servir [`getFetchSize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getFetchSize\(\)).

Comment: lo siento, es que soy nuevo en esto, como le realizo?

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que añadas los campos de respuesta uno a uno dentro de un bucle for, ya que si lo haces directamente vas a tener problemas.

```
for (int i = 0; i < oUsiario.length; i++){
   oUsiario[i] = resultado.getString("formVendiTotal")
}
```

Comment: listo, gracias, ahora como saco la info a una variable, porque mi idea es con la info que me traiga la utilizo para sustituir otra

Comment: si quieres un valor concreto de la variable tan solo debes asignar la posición del valor a dicha variable ```variable=oUsuarui[1]``` por ejemplo.

Comment: Si en cambio, quieres acceder a todos ellos, ahora al tenerlos guardados en una tabla, deberás acceder a ella con un bucle for, cómo en el de la respuesta.

Comment: ya lo hice pero no me sale, voy a subir como quedo y el error